# Scrapy follow previous links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to follow previous year links using scrapy starting from url 'https://umanity.jp/en/racedata/race_6.php'. In this url, current year is 2018 and there is previous button. When you click that button it goes to 2017, 2016 ... until 2000. But scrapy spider I wrote stops at year 2017. My code:

```
import scrapy


class RaceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['umanity.jp']
    start_urls = ['https://umanity.jp/en/racedata/race_6.php']  # start to scrape from this url

    def parse(self, response):
        previous_year_btn = response.xpath('//div[@class="newslist_year_select m_bottom5"]/*[1]')
        if previous_year_btn.extract_first()[1] == 'a':
            href = previous_year_btn.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            follow_link = response.urljoin(href)
            yield scrapy.Request(follow_link, self.parse_years)

    def parse_years(self, response):
        print(response.url)  # prints only year 2017
```

Can't figure out why it stops at 2017 and doesn't go to previous years. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `parse_years` function doesn't look for any further links.

Switch:
`yield scrapy.Request(follow_link, self.parse_years)` 
to
`yield scrapy.Request(follow_link, self.parse)` and all the years are found because the `parse` function continues to find links.

If you do want two separate functions (perhaps, `parse_years` to do something with the data and `parse` to find the next link) it is doable.

`parse_years` would just need this:

```
def parse_years(self, response):
    print(response.url)  # prints only year 2017
    yield from self.parse(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send request to `self.parse`; not `self.parse_years` to achieve the results. I tried to kick out your hardcoded index from xpaths to make it less prone to break. Try the below approach:

```
class RaceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['umanity.jp']
    start_urls = ['https://umanity.jp/en/racedata/race_6.php']  # start to scrape from this url

    def parse(self, response):
        previous_year_btn = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"newslist_year_select")]/a')
        if 'race_prev.gif' in previous_year_btn.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first():
            href = previous_year_btn.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), self.parse)
            print(response.url)
```

However, keeping the second method alive:

```
def parse(self, response):      
    yield scrapy.Request(response.url, self.parse_years)  #this is the fix

    previous_year_btn = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"newslist_year_select")]/a')
    if 'race_prev.gif' in previous_year_btn.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first():
        href = previous_year_btn.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), self.parse)

def parse_years(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```